# mysql use different fields in where clause if one is empty

Tags: mysql

I have table users, which contains fields main_specialization(int) and additional_specizalizations(varchar). First field is number - specialization id. Second field is string, which contains several ids with commas(example '1,2,3').
I should select records with certain main_specialization, and if it's empty, i should use additional. So, i have two parts:

```
main_specialization = some_number
```

and

```
FIND_IN_SET(some_number, additional_specizalizations) > 0
```

How can I unite this conditions in one?

Comment: `A OR (!A AND B)`

Comment: You can exploit the `CASE` construct. Check this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp.

Comment: Your `additional_specizalizations` column violates [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).  Unless you have ***very*** good reason to do otherwise, you should move all of your specialisations (main and additional) to a separate table e.g. `user_specialisations (user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, specialisation INT NOT NULL, is_main BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE, PRIMARY KEY (user_id, specialisation), FOREIGN KEY (user_id)  REFERENCES users (id))`.

Comment: of course I know it, but there are a lot of places in project depend on this structure, and nobody will change this field type